# Permmison Denied to create folders When I using Django project on ubuntu16.04

Tags: python, django, permissions

I have previewed some questions about permission problems when someone is asking when they use Django projects, which is the result of www-data permission.
Here even though I give 777 permission to all files and file holder in the Django project, I still can't create a folder.

```
drwxrwxrwx 4 www-data www-data  4096 Mar  3 11:40 blog
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 38912 Mar  1 16:52 db.sqlite3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data   539 Mar  1 16:37 manage.py
drwxrwxrwx 3 root     root      4096 Mar  3 11:49 media
drwxrwxrwx 3 www-data www-data  4096 Mar  3 11:38 project
```

In my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import os

from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello World')

def create(request):
    if(os.mkdir("hello/")):
        return HttpResponse("success")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("failed")
# Create your views here.
```

Here is the error information:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'hello/'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://58.87.85.248/create/
Django Version: 2.0.2
Exception Type: PermissionError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'hello/'
Exception Location: /var/www/html/project/blog/views.py in create, line 10
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.5.2
Python Path:    
['/var/www/html/project',
 '/usr/lib/python35.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 3 Mar 2018 04:58:45 +0000
```

Thank you very much for viewing my problems.

Comment: First, 777 is a bad solution to solve permission problems. Second, who are you logged in as on the server? If root, and you're trying to get that media directory, you might need to `chown` on that directory.

Comment: Thank you man.  But I think in apache2 www-data is the user and I have already chown the files and folder with www-data.

Comment: What user is Django running under?

Answer (score 1):

chmod 777 determines file mode but chown determines file/folder owner. Verify the folder (not files) is owned by the same user of the process that is trying to write to it. You can try to specify file and folder ownership recursively with

```
chown -R username:username /path/to/folder
```

Comment: Thanks, man. But I have already change the file and folder ownership to www-data which is required by apache2 user as you can see in my questions, like this: drwxrwxrwx 3 www-data www-data  4096 Mar  3 11:38 project